# Finding derivate of function in R

Tags: r

I am using R and trying to make an function by giving 2 parameters which are function and x, try to look for the answer of the function. But I kept getting error. I do not want to use any packages just solely R base. 
Heres the Code so far.

```
test2 <- function(x) {
  func <- expression(x)
  der<- D(eval(func), 'x')
  return(der(x))
}
test2(function(x) return(x^2))
```

I kept getting this error: "expression must not be type 'closure'"
Is there any way that I can structure of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substitute` to pass the expression to `D`:

```
test2 <- function(e, d) D(substitute(e), deparse(substitute(d)))

test2(sin(cos(x + y^2)), x)
#-(cos(cos(x + y^2)) * sin(x + y^2))
```

You cannot pass a function to `D` since it's designed for creating derivatives symbolically, which means it needs expressions containing simple functions known to `D`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight adjustment to get the derivation function working:

```
test2 <- function(x) D(parse(text=x), "x")

test2("sin(cos(x + y^2))")
# -(cos(cos(x + y^2)) * sin(x + y^2))

test2("x^2")
# 2 * x

test2("x^3")
# 3 * x^2
```

Comment: Instead of character, is there any other way that I can put function type?

Comment: What do you mean by a function type? Do you mean an `expression`?

Comment: I mean instead of parameter of "test("x^2") which the parameter is character type, is there any other way that I can use "test(function(x) return(x^2))?

Answer (score 0):

The function `f` returns a character vector, and `string_der` gives the derivative. (I used string manipulation inside since it seems you want to pass an argument.)

```
string_der <- function(x) {
  D(parse(text = x), "x")
}

library(stringr)

f <- function(x) {
  str <- "sin(cos(z + y^2))"
  str <-  str_replace(str, "z",  x)   
  return(str)
}

string_der(f(x = "x"))
# -(cos(cos(x + y^2)) * sin(x + y^2))
```

I guess following is pretty much Adam Queck has done. It uses `quote` and let's you pass an object wrapped in `quote`.

```
quote_der <- function(x) {
  D(eval(x), 'x')
}

f <- function(x) {
  qt <- substitute(expression(sin(cos(z + y^2))), list(z = x))
  return(qt)
}

quote_der(f(x = quote(x)))
#-(cos(cos(x + y^2)) * sin(x + y^2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- the function passed as the argument has a one-line body and
- if x is not specified it defaults to the name of the first argument to the input function

then we can write

```
test3 <- function(fun, x = names(formals(fun))[1]) D(body(fun), x)

test3(function(x) x^2)
## 2 * x
```